# git: I merged master into develop, now what?

Tags: git

I'm a one man shop and I've been working on a development branch for quite a while. I wanted to merge the branches and get back to one branch...master. Somehow, and I'm not sure how, I merged the branches and now I'm on develop.

Should I somehow delete one of the branches?

How do I fix this to have one branch and it be master?

Comment: After you've merged `git checkout master && git branch -D develop`. Now you're on `master` branch and `develop` is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout master
```

The above command will put you in the master branch

```
git merge develop
```

Above will bring whatever is in the develop branch into your master branch

```
git branch -d develop
```

Above will delete the develop branch

However, i suggest keeping the develop branch.

Comment: Why do you suggest keeping the branch?

Comment: Another note. In case you're not, you should be pushing your branches to a remote repository as well.

Comment: Although you don't really need to because you will retain the develop branch commit history in your master, I find it easier to look through history of your develop branch. Your main branch which in your case is master should have very little action on it. I prefer to 'play' with other branches and leave the main as robust as possible. Little more safety imo.

Comment: While I have some git wisdom here, let me ask: how do you guys deal with image assets?

Comment: Haven't dealt with that. Here's a potentially helpful link. https://help.github.com/articles/rendering-and-diffing-images/

Answer (score 1):

Commit and push your changes on your current branch then do:

```
git merge development
git checkout development
git merge master
git branch -D development
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong? Y delete branch development , when u are in branch development. And Why you merge master into development?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add these for your convenience. When you are going with continuous development, it's better you follow a particular branching model. I think [git-flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) will be one model suits for you. Or you can follow your own convenient one.

The key points you want to know are

- Keep **develop** branch for continuous integration of development.
- Start implementing a particular feature form a **feature branch** derived from **develop** branch.
- After you are ready to put a stable release, merge all the changes from **develop** branch to **master**, and put the release. Make sure **mater** always has a stable version.

For your particular question, I would answer this way.

```
git checkout master
git pull development
```

I don't recommend you to delete development branch.